# SAP CRYSTAL REPORTS Parameter - force upper case

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I have a report in SAP Crystal Report that uses an Oracle SQL with parameters.
One of the parameters a user could possibly enter lower case which would not return any values.
I would like to force the parameter entered to be upper case.
EXAMPLE:

User enters p_Parameter something like:
userid1,  UserID1,  UserId1,  Userid1
But in the database the FieldName is USERID1
I can prompt the user to enter as UPPER CASE; but they could still miss it.

I have tried:

**Works as is requiring user to enter p_Parameter in UPPER CASE:**

```
WHERE FieldName IN {?p_Parameter}
```

**Returns errors:  missing right parenthesis.**

```
WHERE FieldName IN UPPER({?p_Parameter})  

WHERE FieldName IN (UCASE({p_Parameter})
```

I got some more feedback on this elsewhere that I don't believe this is possible, because FieldName is a list in this case so it can't be wrapped in upper().. when it comes into the sql it looks like ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')

I'm still leaving this as un-answered in case some Crystal Reports expert out there knows of a possibility of making this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to create a new formula field, which returns an array based on the values of your {?p_Parameter} array, and change all contained elements to upperstring. Then you can use the new formula field in your record selection instead of the parameter field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
{fieldname} in "['"&UCase(join({?parameter},"','"))&"']"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.